# How to insert a record with many-to-one relationship fields?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have model

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Order } from './order.entity';
import { People } from '../../people/entities/people.entity';

@Entity('order_people')
export class OrderPeople {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Order)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'order_id',
  })
  order: Order;

  @ManyToOne(() => People)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'people_id'
  })
  people: People;

  @Column({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 15,
    scale: 4
  })
  price: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'int'
  })
  quantity: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 15,
    scale: 4
  })
  cost: number;
}
```

trying to insert data

```
[
  { peopleId: 1, orderId: 1, price: 122.4533, quantity: 2 },
  { peopleId: 2, orderId: 1, price: 244.4433, quantity: 2 }
]
```

I insert data through queryBuilder like this

```
await this.orderPeopleRepository.createQueryBuilder('insert')
.insert().
values(updatePeopleDto)
.execute()
```

The records are inserted into the database, but the peopleId and orderId fields are null. How can this problem be solved? I don’t want to do it through connections in Order, because I created a separate service, so that in the future it would be convenient to maintain and expand the functionality + SOLID

Comment: You named the relation as ```people``` and ```order```. But in insert data, you have named the relation as ```peopleId``` and ```orderId```. the insert data should have the same name as that of relation.